# Adding days to a timestamp displaying odd number

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add 7 days to a timestamp stored in a MySQL Database.

I am using `strtotime` : `echo strtotime("+7 days",$result["datetime"]);`

but i get this result `606813`

when i `echo $result["dateimte"];` i get this : `2013-07-23 04:35:27`

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: maybe `echo strtotime($result["datetime"]." +7 days");` [check here](http://codepad.org/AWdoloQi)

Comment: I have changes my code please check below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtotime()` expects the second argument to be a Unix timestamp, not a string formatted with the MySQL DateTime format.

You will first need to convert the result from MySQL into a Unix timestamp, and `strtotime()` should do what you need:

```
strtotime($result["datetime"]."+7 days");
```

The above function will output: `1375158927`, which equates to Tue, 30 Jul 2013 04:35:27.

Comment: Where's the check if strtotime succeeds? Why strtotime and not `DateTime`?

Comment: You can `strtotime` just once, no need to call the function twice.

Answer (score 0):

the following will explain what you should do:

```
$d = strtotime("+7 days",strtotime("2013-07-23 04:35:27"));
echo date("d.m.Y H:i:s",$d);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code -

```
$date=strtotime($result["datetime"]);

echo $newDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime('+7 days',$date));
```